# regex for N (1 to 3 digit) numbers in square brackets with commas+spaces between them

Tags: javascript, regex, citations

I'm going to try to phrase this clearly... (I'm pretty new at regex). I'm working on a PDF document, with a program called AutoBookmark (from Evermap). I'm trying to set it up to link numbered citations to numbered references in a bibliography.

The goal is to match each numbered citation within brackets, and return that number within brackets, alone. In other words, if I have [85], I'd just return [85]. If I have [85, 93], I'd return both [85] and [93]. If there are more numbers in brackets, up to N numbers, I'd return N of them (in brackets). If there is a range, i.e., [85-93], I only need to return the first.

So it seems to me I'm asking this: the number (1 to 3 digits), only if preceded by EITHER an opening bracket, OR another number followed by a comma and a space, but only if that number is preceded by an opening bracket OR by a number followed by a comma and a space, but only if... you get the picture. Iterate until you hit a bracket (then return the number) or a non-number, in which case, don't return the number.
Is this something even reasonable to ask of a regular expression? Or, since I'm doing this in a PDF, must I do a Javascript routine? (which BTW, I also don't know how to do!)
Thanks! I know I'm a newbie at this, and I'm grateful for any thoughts.

Comment: There are two things I don't understand: 1) Why is this tagged `javascript`? Can this AutoBookmark program execute javascript? 2) What exactly do you mean by "_return_ the number within brackets"? Do you just want to replace all occurences of `[1, 2]` with `[1][2]` or something else (e.g. run some code for each regex match)?

Comment: I know... I have no training and I'm sure I'm saying it wrong. But, basically, yes. It's the equivalent of "replace all occurrences".  What I've come up with (which doesn't quite answer the mail) is `((?<=\[)|(?<=(\d, )))(\d{1,3})`. This captures too much, because there might be sequences of numbers in the text, too, which I don't want. If I have to, I can live with that - I'd rather have a couple of extra wrong links than miss any.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with this program, but [this](https://regex101.com/r/VA4zgk/8) should work with javascript, and thus other feature-minimal implementations of Regex.

`\[?\s*(\d+)\s*(?=(?:,\s*\d+)+|\])(?=[^\[]*\]).`

```
\[?          # Literal [, zero or 1 times
\s*          # Any number (*) of whitespace characters
(\d+)        # Any number of digits, one or more (+)
\s*          # Any number (*) of whitespace characters
(?=          # Positive lookahead, support for possitive lookahead is key to the regex
  (?:        # Open non-capturing group
    ,\s*\d+  # Literal ",", any number of whitespace characters, 
               # digits one or more
  )          # Close non-capturing group
|            # or
  \]         # Literal "]"
)            # Close positive lookahead
(?=          # Open another positive lookahead
  [^\[]*\]   # Any number of characters that are not "[", as long as they're followed by "]".
               # This is only a validation check, those characters won't be caught
)            # Close positive lookahead
.            # Match any character except newline
```

If this program supports variable-length bookbehinds, you can use this, which only adds a lookbehind to makesure the number is prefixed by valid characters as well.

`\[?\s*(?<=\[[,\d ]*)(\d+)\s*(?=(?:,\s*\d+)+|\])(?=[^\[]*\]).`

If your citation format is 100% reliable `[1]`, `[12]`, `[13, 14, 21]`, etc. You can use a [simpler version](https://regex101.com/r/VA4zgk/9)

`\[?\s*(\d+)(?=(?:, \d+)|\])(?=[^\[]*\]).` or this if your program supports variable-length lookbehinds, `\[(?<=\[[,\d ]*)(\d+)(?=(?:, \d+)|\])(?=[^\[]*\]).`.

**With any of these expressions**: You can change the last character, **`.`**, to **`\]?`** to see the citations still separated by commas `[1],[15],[22]`.

`*` In many flavors of regular expressions, lookbehinds--*if supported at all*, must be a fixed-length with no quantifiers and all alternation being the same width. For instance, `(?<=a|1)` will work but `(?<=a|12)`, `(<=a|1+)` or  `(<=a+)` will fail. As will quantifiers applied to the lookbehind itself `(?<=a)+`

Edit: And thanks for Rawing for input.

Comment: Nice regex, but there are a few details you can improve: 1) `(?:\[\s*|\s*)` could be just `\[?\s*`. 2) At the first lookahead, you match `\s*` twice in a row: `\s*(?=...|\s*\])` This can be dangerous and can be simplified to `\s*(?=...|\])`. 3) If you change `,\s*\d+` to `[,-]\s*\d+` it will also match citations of the form `[1-2]`.

Comment: @Rawing You're right for certain on counts 1 and 2, and while the `-` support is a nice feature in many citation regexes, I felt it would be out of place here. Thanks, especially for catching the accidental double `\s*`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions! Here's what happens. Apparently, Evermap doesn't understand variable-length lookarounds, so I tried your other ones. They give some results, but not all. They match simple numbers in brackets, and they match the last number in a series within brackets.

AutoBookmark does offer a "multiple rule" way of searching for text patterns, so I could look for [35] or [35 or , 35] or , 35, or 35- all individually.

Right now, I'm using three rules:

`(\[)(\d{1,3})(\]|,)`

`\[?\s*(\d+)(?=(?:, \d+)|\])(?=[^\[]*\]).`

`(\[|\s)(\d{1,3})\-`

For each of these, the 'replace', or what the program calls 'link action', is the extracted number, or `\2`.

This gets me most of what I want, but if there are more than two numbers in a series, separated by comma+space, it doesn't match the middle numbers. I would do that by hand, I suppose, if I can't find a better way.

I know I'm stumbling around here... Thanks for helping, and thanks for being patient with a newbie! (If I work this out so it's fully automated, I'll be a god at work...)